# GWT Tree Item:How to add image to tree item?

Tags: gwt, tree

I am using gwt 2.3 version.I am using gwt tree in my application.
Here is my code:

```
  public void onModuleLoad() {
// Create a tree with a few items in it.
TreeItem root = new TreeItem("root");
root.addItem("item0");
root.addItem("item1");
root.addItem("item2");

// Add a CheckBox to the tree
TreeItem item = new TreeItem(new CheckBox("item3"));
root.addItem(item);

Tree t = new Tree();
t.addItem(root);

// Add it to the root panel.
RootPanel.get().add(t);
```

}

There is a item with check box.I want add image to this tree item.But I am not able to do this as I already added one widget check box.Is there any other way add image to tree item with check box??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TreeItem has a TreeItem(Widget w) constructor.

You can put anything you want in there. So write a small widget that has an image and text next to each other in a div and the Tree will render it correctly.

You are already using it in your example code. So just write one more widget that combines the CheckBox with an image in a FlowPanel or HorizontalPanel. Whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that made me whack my head for a while also. Basically I found 2 options:

1. Use SmartGWT, it has nice customizable tree widgets that let you change the pictures of the nodes:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#tree_databinding_local

1. Use GWT's tree-image:

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TreeImages.html

If you ask me, SmartGWT is somewhat demanding and rigid, and you might not like the fact that it doesn't let you go to the low leves like GWT does but it does have a nice set of customizable tree widgets. TreeImage on the other hand lets you still work with pure GWT (which I think is better overall), but it doesn't let you customize the tree as much as Smart GWT does

Comment: I am not going to use smart gwt as using gwt in whole application.And for other option it for tree opening and closing not for tree items